# How to display certain data in certain areas of a div?

Tags: php, mysql

I have recently been working on a tournament bracket system that I am trying to display data through with PHP and MySQL. The jsfiddle of the design is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7b572uzn/5/embedded/result/) but the code can be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7b572uzn/5/). Anyways, I have created a database to have displayed in the tournament bracket.

```
CREATE TABLE `tournament_bracket` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
   `tournamentname` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
   `round` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
   `position` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
   `player` varchar(64) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

So the way I am trying to identify where the player belongs is through the round and position. Here is a basic representation of how the round and position will work. 
http://gyazo.com/edcf23ccb1d827eb4e9080cfa62ba3ce

So, even though there might be 5 positions all with the id of "1", the round will point them to the correct one. Now, I am trying to approach a way I can make it displayed through the design. I understand the basic concept of grabbing information from the database and displaying it through PHP. But, looking at the code, I need something to count the amount of times a row is created. For example

```
<div class="round quarter-finals"> (round one)
<div class="round semi-finals"> (round two)
<div class="round finals">  (round three)
<div class="round">  (round four)
<div class="roundfinal"> (round five)
```

If for everytime one of those is mentioned It would count a number, I could determine where I should put the row at. As for the position I still do not have any ideas.

I figure I need to give each player slot an id and each round an id as well. I am unsure how to do this, can anyone elaborate?

Comment: Use the primary key from your table..

Comment: Please include any relevant existing code directly in your question, not just on external sites.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, your concern is about the design of the database.

An appropriate minimalist design could be :
player (playerID, name)
tournament (tournamentID, name)
match(matchID, tournamentID, player1ID, player2ID, nextMatchID)

For easier implementation, you could add a value 'round' in the match table as you suggested.
match(matchID, round, tournamentID, player1ID, player2ID, nextMatchID)

Comment: I'm mainly concerned with the way it will be displayed. I have no knowledge on displaying data within certain areas. I thought about using 2 players, but was unsure. It does seem it would be easier to have two players in one row of data to determine the area easier.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I don't understand what is your issue.

Comment: In your PHP script you have to query your database in SQL. Just do a sort in SQL Query and loop in your script on records returned to add the HTML.

Comment: Yes but a simple query to grab the data won't display it in the right area, that is where my trouble begins.